# Apply os.path.join method within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, os.path

I have a DataFrame `df` with three columns columns: `['Name', 'WD', 'File']`. The file associated with each name in `'Name'` is given as its working directory in column `'WD'` and the file name in column `'File'`.

[My df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzvt1.png)

I want to join the `'WD'` column and `'File'` column using `os.path.join()` method such that the `'File'` column shows the full path.

I tried the following script and it works okay but I was wondering if there is a better way without using the for loop:

```
for i in df.index:
    df['File'][i]=os.path.join(df['WD'][i],df['File'][i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy solution is to use `os.sep` instead of `os.path.join()`.

```py
>>> df["Path"] = df["WD"] + os.sep + df["File"]
```

Answer (score 9):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61880480/104707) is perfectly fine and the most readable, but just for completeness and maybe different use cases, here are two more options:

1. Use `cat` (concatenate), one of Pandas' many [string functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#method-summary):

   ```
   df['WD'].str.cat(df['File'], sep=os.sep)
   ```
2. [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) *any* function to rows or columns:

   ```
   df[['WD', 'File']].apply(lambda row: os.path.join(*row), axis=1)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Both these options worked. Will be using these methods for other use conditions.